# calculate episodes in R

Tags: r

Hello would love to get some advice how to approach in R

I have a dataset one minute intervals for a year with 3 columns, "device" "time" and "values"

for example:

```
'803293'    '9/30/2021 16:04'   '95'
'803293'    '9/30/2021 16:05'   '92'
'803293'    '9/30/2021 16:06'   '91'
'803293'    '9/30/2021 16:08'   '96'
'803293'    '9/30/2021 16:09'   '91'
'803293'    '9/30/2021 16:09'   '95'
```

I would like to create a data.frame that would calculate the length of episodes with values < 95, along with start time, for example from the above table 1st occurrence at 9/30/2021 16:05 for the duration of 2 minutes while the 2nd occurance is at 9/30/2021 16:0 for the duration of 1 minute, so I am wondering if it is possible to create a data frame as below?

```
 'device'      'time'    'Duration'  
'803293'    '9/30/2021 16:05'   '2'
'803293'    '9/30/2021 16:09'   '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(stevemisc)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'stevemisc'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     tbl_df
  
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~device, ~time, ~values, 
'803293',    '9/30/2021 16:04',   95,
'803293',    '9/30/2021 16:05',   92,
'803293',    '9/30/2021 16:06',   91,
'803293',    '9/30/2021 16:08',   96,
'803293',    '9/30/2021 16:09',   91,
'803293',    '9/30/2021 16:09',   95,
'803294',    '9/30/2021 16:04',   95,
'803294',    '9/30/2021 16:05',   92,
'803294',    '9/30/2021 16:06',   91,
'803294',    '9/30/2021 16:08',   93,
'803294',    '9/30/2021 16:09',   91,
'803294',    '9/30/2021 16:09',   95)

dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(event = values >= 95)

dat <- sbtscs(dat, event, time, device)
dat %>% 
  group_by(device) %>% 
  mutate(spell_num = cumsum(c(1, lag(event)[-1]))) %>% 
  filter(!event) %>% 
  group_by(device, spell_num) %>% 
  summarise(start_time = first(time), 
            Duration = n()) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-spell_num)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'device'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   device start_time      Duration
#>   <chr>  <chr>              <int>
#> 1 803293 9/30/2021 16:05        2
#> 2 803293 9/30/2021 16:09        1
#> 3 803294 9/30/2021 16:05        4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

To explain, in the package `stevemisc` which can be installed from CRAN, there is a function called `sbtscs()` that calculates the amount of time until an event happens.  Here, I've defined the event as being greater than or equal to 95 on `values`.  The rest is data management so a spell number can be identified and then taking the total number of time points and the starting time.  I took the liberty of adding another device with different properties to make sure it works with multiple devices.